# PHP / CodeIgniter - $_FILES being ignored completely

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following in my view

```
<input class="file" name="mpfile[]" type="file" size="32" />
```

In my controller, i have the following code.

```
if(isset($_FILES['mpfile'])) {
    echo 'testing';
}
```

Fairly simple yes? .... Except that every time i run it, no matter if i have choosen a file or not, it runs ... Should it only run the echo if i have a file ready for input?

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)` and see what it outputs.

Comment: post all your code; also try and re-create CI's basic file uploader @ http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your FORM element has the following attributes:

`method="POST"`

and

`enctype="multipart/form-data"`

- Christian

Comment: Also worth noting if you are using the form helper to change from `form_open()` to `form_open_multipart()`

Answer (score 2):

check your PHP.ini for:

```
file_uploads = "1"
post_max_size = 50000
upload_max_file_size = 2M
```

do a `phpinfo();`

*disclaimer* php.ini values might be slightly off, but you'll find them I'm sure. the names are right, not sure if the values are.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(isset($_FILES['mpfile']['name']) && $_FILES['mpfile']['name'])
  {
    echo 'testing';
   }
```

Comment: Nope ... Still didnt work, could it have anything to do with the [] after the mpfile

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `<input>` is embedded in a `<form>` that does a `POST` on your script, have you tried dumping `$_FILES`? E.g.:

```
if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
  {
     print '<pre>'.var_export($_FILES,TRUE).'</pre>';
  }
```

Can you post a result? Also, are uploads enabled for PHP?

Comment: Its printing out the array perfect ... if theres a file, it will say the filename, size, tmp_name and all that ... and if there is no file, it will display an empty array ... yet the code is still being displayed both times

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Codeigniter's upload class. Codeigniter could be emptying `$_FILES` along with the other globals.

Maybe try dumping `$_FILES` at the top of codeigniters index.php to make sure

Comment: I am using the upload class ... that doesnt include the isset($_FILES) bit ... that should be a simple PHP thing

Comment: @Chris - Sorry I misread your question. Why don't you try `empty($_FILES[['mpfile'])` instead.

Comment: Just to clarify - you tried: `if(!empty($_FILES['mpfile']))` and it printed the text regardless?

Comment: yepo ... ive tried all the suggestions here :( ... driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

Here's another stab in the dark. Check the error code:

```
if($_FILES['mpfile']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
     echo 'testing'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check for an empty file:

```
if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['error'] != 4)
```

See this post:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/136610/#673652

"The upload field gets put into $_FILES even if it is empty and the error and size are set to 4 and 0 respectively"

Edit to add:

I've never uploaded multiple, but I think in your case you would add `['mpfile']` before each `['userfile']` in the test

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_FILES['mpfile']['name'])) {
    var_dump($_FILES['mpfile']['name']);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: in the example he create an empty array that mean isset will return true i use the invert of empty to work around that

Answer (score 0):

You are defining an array:

```
<input class="file" name="mpfile[]" type="file" size="32" />
```

In PHP the variable `$_FILES['mpfile']` will be also an (empty) array.
If you now test with `isset` then it is set because it's an array (and never null).

Test with `empty()`.